# jQuery element width (Chrome bug)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I reload the page with F5 width of element is **100**. If I just click on internal link or press enter in browser-line width is **1847**. In the Firefox, everything is fine. How to fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("#element").outerWidth());
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post an example or you're full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`.

You'll likely have images/iframes etc that are being reloaded when doing F5, but used from cache normally.

The window load event waits for those images to load; the document ready event doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(window).resize()` :

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  console.log($("#element").outerWidth());
});
```